# Create an automated R script using taskscheduleR

Tags: r

I trying to create some automated R scripts using the taskscheduleR library. I have created the following script:

```
library(lubridate)
setwd("C:/Users/Marc/Desktop/")


create_df <- function(){
 list <- c(1,2,3)
 df <- data.frame(list)

 x <- format(Sys.time(), "%S")
 name <- paste0("name_", x, ".csv")

 write.csv(df, name)
}
create_df()
```

That can be fired up with the following:

```
myscript <- "C:/Users/Marc/Dropbox/PROJECTEN/Lopend/taskschedulR_test/test.R"


taskscheduler_create(taskname = "myfancyscript", rscript = myscript, 
                     schedule = "ONCE", starttime = format(Sys.time() + 62, "%H:%M"))
```

However when I execute it nothing happens. Any thoughts on how I can get this running?

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me, I've now got a .csv called "name_03". I have the script within the folder that the output goes into, unlike yours which is in your dropbox. You could check the event log by looking at the history tab on the Task Scheduler, type this into R:

```
system("control schedtasks")
```